# Creating a basic monorepo setup that can get incremental updates to packages

Tags: create-react-app, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I would like to create a monorepo that uses very basic components (prefereably no Nx, Rush, Turborepo, etc)

I want to have an "app" e.g. created by create-react-app in the repo, and then some other miscellaneous components that are used by the app in separate packages in the monorepo

I have not found a way where the component packages can easily be incrementally recompiled without me manually going in and running the build on that individual component package though

I am looking at typescript "project references" to see if this can help, but I am not sure I have it fully wired up as I need. I don't yet have a command that has the incremental builds.

Example here
https://github.com/cmdcolin/monorepo_template

Summary

- `workspace-a` - contains React components, depends on `workspace-b`
- `workspace-b` - contains React components, no dependencies
- `app` - a `create-react-app` instance, renders a React component from `workspace-a`

How can I make it so that when I have `yarn start` in the app directory, then changes to workspace-a or workspace-b will be auto-updated on the webpage? Adding another sub-command running in another window is fine also

Comment: related thread from the create-react-app github issues https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1333